# Previous permute of Steinhaus Johnson-Trotter

Tags: algorithm, permutation

I'm using Steinhaus Johnson-Trotter algorithm with this implementation: https://github.com/nodash/steinhaus-johnson-trotter

I'm wondering how can I make function something like "previous" permute.

Example:

```
const t = trotter([4, 2, 1, 3])
t.next() // [ 4, 2, 3, 1 ]
t.back() // [4, 2, 1, 3] <- this is what I need
```

I'm trying to find any pattern in how it can be possible to make a reverse function but without results.

EDIT:
I've tried with change:
`moveTo = maxIndex - directions[maxIndex];`

But it not works for all cases, take a look:

```
const numbers = [4, 2, 1, 3];

const t = trotter(numbers); // [4, 2, 1, 3] | [ 0, 1, 2, 3 ] [ 0, -1, -1, -1 ]
t.next(); // [ 4, 2, 3, 1 ] | [ 0, 1, 3, 2 ] [ 0, -1, -1, -1 ]
t.next(); // [ 4, 3, 2, 1 ] | [ 0, 3, 1, 2 ] [ 0, -1, -1, -1 ]
t.next(); // [ 3, 4, 2, 1 ] | [ 3, 0, 1, 2 ] [ 0, 0, -1, -1 ]

t.prev(); // it should be [4, 3, 2, 1] but the output is [3, 4, 2, undefined ]
```

Best,

Answer (score 0):

Seems the only change needed:

```
moveTo = maxIndex + directions[maxIndex];
  to
moveTo = maxIndex - directions[maxIndex];
```

Comment: Does it work when you start from 2134 (last permutation in throtter order)?

Comment: For the last no but for penultimate yes. But 3 from the end also not working.

Comment: If we start from the last, directions should update properly (I hope)

Comment: What do you mean? Basically your solution does not cover all cases. Take a look at my edited post.